# Path manipulation issue in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, path-manipulation

I am using this code to read all the files in Java folder with which are ending with ".properties".

```
@Value("classpath*:com/tech/java/*.properties")
    private Resource[] files;
```

---

```
for (Resource resource : files) {

File file = resource.getFile();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
```

Fortify scan is failing at `try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))` with the security vulnerability saying that there is a chance of path manipulation.

Comment: this may help -  [Fortify Path Manipulation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263056/fortify-path-manipulation-error)

Comment: How to create the whitelist for my filepath. can you please help me with this.